# iframe transform scale only works on localhost

Tags: css, transform, scale

I successfully have implemented a zoom-in/zoom-out button on the content of an `<iframe/>` following [this simple recipe](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_transform).

The trick is that you dynamically change a style (transform scale) argument in JavaScript that is applied to a `div`.

The problem is that this example and my newly built page would only scale resp. turn on localhost, but not if called by url. The transform scale command is not working and the button click does not change anything.

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, somewhere I found it: Adding:

meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/

did the job.

PS: I was not able to post the meta tag correctly as I couldn't type it as Code or HTML. Just add an inicial '<' and a '>' in the end!